# Could I call "give me a place to stand on, and I will move the Earth" a saying, an aphorism, an apothegm and an adage?

Tags: vocabulary

[From the Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/saying)

> saying: a well-known wise statement that often has a meaning that is different from the simple meanings of the words it contains
>
> adage: a wise saying
>
> aphorism: a short clever saying that is intended to express a general truth
>
> apothegm: a short clever saying that is intended to express a general truth

I understand the sentence "Give me a place to stand on, and I will move the Earth" is what Archimedes said about the Law of the Lever, I'd just like to know whether I could call it a saying, an aphorism, an apothegm and an adage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's certainly a "saying".  As your definitions suggest, an "adage" is supposed to be conspicuously "wise", or even "philosophical". An adage often gives advice "Don't count your chickens before they hatch." Most adages don't have a known author.

An aphorism is meant to be particularly eloquent, and more often has a known author. It is notably short or terse "Power tends to corrupt, and absolute power corrupts absolutely."

I've never heard the term apophthegm. It seems to be a synonym of aphorism.

You could use any of these words.

Some words seem to breed synonyms:

- Adage
- Aphorism
- Apophthegm
- Brocard
- Epigram
- Maxim
- Principle
- Proverb
- Saying

and probably others

Comment: Thank you so much. How about axiom, remark, old saying, truism and quote?

Comment: Yes, add those to the list.

Comment: A quote has a known author, and a truism is seeming wise but actually empty statement.